# QUALIFY equivalent in HIVE / SPARK SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am trying to convert a `Teradata SQL` query into `HIVE/Spark SQL` equivalent. Is there any substitute for `qualify` along with `count`

```
SELECT
PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID
from db.source_table
QUALIFY COUNT(CHILD_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY  PARENT_ID)=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Got it :)**

```
select 
PARENT_ID, 
CHILD_ID
from 
(select PARENT_ID, CHILD_ID, 
    count(CHILD_ID) over (partition by PARENT_ID order by PARENT_ID asc) as COUNT_PARENT_ID 
    from db.source_table
) where COUNT_PARENT_ID = 0
```